# Como dar ALIAS com "mes/ano" atual?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select, concatenação-de-string

Considerando a consulta abaixo, preciso que o ALIAS onde existe as SOMAS, fique como "nomeMes/anoAtual" ("ABR/14","MAI/14"...) de forma dinâmica.

```
    SELECT      fornecedor.codigo, UPPER(fornecedor.razaosocial) AS fornecedor, 
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())   AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 4)),2)  AS 'ABR/14',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())   AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 5)),2)  AS 'MAI/14',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())   AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 6)),2)  AS 'JUN/14',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())   AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 7)),2)  AS 'JUL/14',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())   AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 8)),2)  AS 'AGO/14',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())   AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 9)),2)  AS 'SET/14',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())   AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 10)),2) AS 'OUT/14',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())   AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 11)),2) AS 'NOV/14',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())   AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 12)),2) AS 'DEZ/14',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())+1 AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 1)),2)  AS 'JAN/15',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())+1 AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 2)),2)  AS 'FEV/15',
                FORMAT(SUM((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(rel_pedido.valortotal),0) FROM rel_pedido WHERE rel_pedido.cod_pedido = pedido.codigo AND YEAR(pedido.dt_pedido) = YEAR(NOW())+1 AND MONTH(pedido.dt_pedido) = 3)),2)  AS 'MAR_15'
    FROM        pedido
    INNER JOIN  fornecedor ON fornecedor.codigo     = pedido.fornecedor
    WHERE       pedido.fornecedor = 5
    GROUP BY    fornecedor.codigo
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode gerar um arquivo de texto com um separador padrão e acrescentar a primeira linha manualmente com as colunas que desejar. Geralmente esse tipo de query é para relatório, então, se seu cenário permitir, pode importar o arquivo "csv" em qualquer excel da vida.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível definir um alias de maneira dinâmica. A SQL não é sua amiga na hora de obter do banco colunas que você não sabe quais são.

Considere criar uma stored procedure que gere o comando SQL dinamicamente, concatenando como alias uma variável gerada à parte. Então você pode obter o resultado da stored procedure no seu aplicativo em vez de enviar este comando SELECT.